# When to delegate events with GWT

Tags: events, gwt

When would be an appropriate time to delegate events with GWT using:

```
void com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.delegateEvent
```

Usually events dispatched by browser bubble up the node so I can't think of the reason why you would need to manually delegate the events.
A real use case would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parent.delegateEvent(child, event)` is actually the same as `child.fireEvent(event)`.

`fireEvent` was originally a `protected` method so `delegateEvent` was added to expose it publicly ([issue 3263](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3263)), then `fireEvent` was made public as part of [another change](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=4494)

It has nothing to do with the *event delegation* pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Event delegation is especially useful in effects like dropdown menus, where lots of events on links may take place that can easily be handled at the root level (an  or  in this case).

Just go through the [blog](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html) just written by  . @Chris Heilmann and @Dan Webb with a [use case demo](http://www.quirksmode.org/focusblurexample.html)

Comment: This has actually nothing to do with it.

Comment: oh...My post answers the question "why you would need to manually delegate the events"...I did'nt think its a GWT specific.